# I have an Unwind segue that does work programmatically but works tied to a button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a app project I am working on. I created an unwind segue in my main view as

```
   @IBAction func unwindToHomeScreen(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

It works from another view from the cancel button

[image]

however in the same view when I call the segue

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToHomeScreen", sender: self)
```

The app crashes with

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<TravelSave.AddVacationTableViewController: 0x7907f380>) has no segue with identifier 'unwindToHomeScreen''
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The complier doesn't know what `unwindToHomeScreen ` is. Have you declared it via code? By the way you don't need code to move the user from a view to another.

Comment: Wouldn't the func unwindToHomeScreen(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) IBAction in my home view do that?

Comment: I'm not understanding too much. Do you want to move the user from a view to another?

Comment: @ddpishere No, you need to set the unwind segue's identifier to "unwindToHomeScreen"

Comment: @CeceXX yes i want to save my data and take the user back to main.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I created the segue programmatically ...it doesn't exist on the storyboard

Comment: @ddpishere I'll post a screencap to explain... One sec...

Comment: @LyndseyScott I just found my mistake...under my View where I attached the Cancel button to the Exit segue I had not put the identifier on it...you led me in the right direction

Comment: @ddpishere Well, I already photoshopped together a screenshot for you, so I've posted it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you say in your comment, that you've "created the segue programmatically," from the screen cap you've posted in your question, it's clear that you've appropriately linked the segue to your cancel button within the storyboard.  Within your storyboard, you need to add an identifier. Select the segue within the view controller scene, then add "unwindToHomeScreen" as an identifier:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping get past this...its always the little things that get ya

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was when I attached my Cancel button to my exit segue I did not put the identifier on the segue shown here

[image]